# How to add multiple language in tinymce (hindi and english)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using `Tinymce editor` and I know `how to change language english to hindi or any other language` but its work only for one language at one time.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '.tinymce',
  language: "hi_IN",
});
```

like this i have change language to hindi but now i can't write in english in editor.
`So is there any way i use both languages`

Or If there `any other EDITOR` that support multiple languages same time please guide me

any help appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to combine more than one language in one editor.

Please refer to this link.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/localization/#language

TinyMce is made for simplicity and easyness. If you want to have more than one language that points to one ID please play around with your Database Design.

Answer (score 0):

Actually now you can add languages in Tinymce by downloading different languages packages and integrating it with your editor.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/localization/

here you will find the list of Available Language Packages and how to use them

Comment: linking to a source is good. but, including code snippets from that link, is much better.